# Trying to use Near to relocate points to the waterways

Tags: arcobjects, c#, feature-layer

We are trying to relocate elements that are near the water but not quite on the water and relocation them to the nearest point.  I'm trying to build the parameters to use the Near tool programmatically with a point on a small island.  It should find the point right away but returns a FAIL error.  Can anyone see why I still get a FAIL???

This is the latest update in code that we tried.  The tool seems to need FeatureSets only so I added logic to create Featuresets from the FeatureClass.

```
    messages.AddMessage("Creating the SearchNear tool.");
    IGPUtilities3 util = new GPUtilitiesClass();
    UID ClsID = new UIDClass();
    ClsID.Value = "{52353152-891A-11D0-BEC6-00805F7C4268}";
    IFeatureWorkspace fws = (IFeatureWorkspace)GPUtilities.GetInMemoryWorkspace();
    IObjectClassDescription objectClassDescription = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();
    IFields fields = objectClassDescription.RequiredFields;
    int shapeFieldIndex = fields.FindField("SHAPE");
    IField field = fields.get_Field(shapeFieldIndex);
    IGeometryDef geometryDef = field.GeometryDef;
    IGeometryDefEdit geometryDefEdit = (IGeometryDefEdit)geometryDef;
    geometryDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = GetSpatialReference();           
    geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint;
    IFeatureClass pointFeature = fws.CreateFeatureClass("tempPointFeatureClass", fields, ClsID, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", string.Empty);
    IFeatureBuffer buffer = pointFeature.CreateFeatureBuffer();
    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = pointFeature.Insert(true);
    IGeometry pointShape = ((IFeature)inputPoint).Shape;
    buffer.Shape = pointShape;
    featureCursor.InsertFeature(buffer);
    featureCursor.Flush();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(featureCursor);
    IFeatureLayer pointFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
    pointFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pointFeature;
    ((ILayer)pointFeatureLayer).Name = pointFeature.AliasName;
    pointFeatureLayer.DataSourceType = "Point Feature Class";
    geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon;
    IFeatureClass polygonFeature = fws.CreateFeatureClass("tempPolyFeatureClass", fields, ClsID, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", string.Empty);
    buffer = polygonFeature.CreateFeatureBuffer();
    featureCursor = polygonFeature.Insert(true);
    ((IGeometry)water).SpatialReference = GetSpatialReference();
    buffer.Shape = (IGeometry)water;
    featureCursor.InsertFeature(buffer);
    featureCursor.Flush();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(featureCursor);
    IFeatureLayer polyFeaturelayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
    polyFeaturelayer.FeatureClass = polygonFeature;
    ((ILayer)polyFeaturelayer).Name = polygonFeature.AliasName;
    polyFeaturelayer.DataSourceType = "Polygon Feature Class";

    Near relocateCompute = new Near()
    {
        in_features =   (FeatureLayer)pointFeatureLayer,
        near_features = (FeatureLayer)polyFeaturelayer,
        location = "LOCATION",
        angle =    "NO_ANGLE",
        method =   "GEODESIC"
    };

      while (incrementor < 4)
      {
    try
    {
        relocateCompute.search_radius = (SearchRadius * incrementor * 1852).ToString() + " Meters";
        IFeatureClass newPoint = (IFeatureClass)RunTool((IGPProcess)relocateCompute, false);
            ....
```

The RunTool method basically encapsulates the whole process of running a tool and the boolean is to determine if a string is returned or a CreateFeaterClassFromString is returned.

Comment: Are you using arcgis?
I may have a solution in modelbuilder if you want a idea.

Comment: We are writing geoprocessing services.  We avoid modelbuilder as we discovered some issues with the extent of processing that we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great deal of research, I found that Near documentation STATES that the second parameter is a FeatureLayer.  However it can contain multiple geographies, so in their usual undocumented way, this tool takes only a string representation of the data.  This opens up so many possibilities of issues that I did not want to think about it.

What I did discover in the next sweep of searches was the Proximity interface.  So once I get my raster converted to a Polygon (actually 1900 polygons) I use the Polygon to create an IProximityOperator, then use the ReturnNearestPoint method.  Much easier than using those idiotic tools!